# fail2ban haproxy regex

Tags: regex, haproxy, fail2ban

by using fail2ban I want to block IPs which match with error 429 in haproxy log.

by using fail2ban I want to block IPs which match with error 429 in haproxy log. I already tried below regex but didn't work. You suggestion is appreciated

`failregex = .*:<HOST>(?::\d+)?\s+.*\d* 429`

`failregex = ^%(__prefix_line)s<HOST>(?::\d+)?\s+.*<NOSRV> -1/-1/-1/-1/\+*\d* 429`

Sample haproxy log

`Feb 16 07:43:51 ip-10-100-212-165 haproxy[1624130]: 158.118.198.219:42990 [16/Feb/2023:07:43:50.242] r_a_i~ it_backup_server/it-server-04-de 0/0/0/1181/1181 429 4436 - - --NI 1211/1210/38/13/0 0/0 "POST / HTTP/1.1"`

Comment: have you tried with fail2ban-regex? Your short rule is working for me. The second one I haven't tested it. It needs the context where __prefix_line is defined. Have you read https://fail2ban.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filters.html ?

Comment: the point is the short rule can't recongnize the client IP properly. it just block IPs like 0.0.127.192

Answer (score 0):

you should adjust the regex into something more generic, like this:

```
^<HOST>.*\s429\s
```

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I followed the [fail2ban-regex documentation](https://fail2ban.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filters.html#developing-testing-a-regex) and used the `-D` option to generate a [Debugexx link](https://www.debuggex.com/r/livCRwzvlTWoJX--). It expands the `<HOST>` clause to something like `(?P<ip4>...)|(?P<ip6>...)|(?P<dns>...)`.

```
.*:<HOST>(?::\d+)?\s+.*\d* 429

# captured group: 42997 - WRONG
```

Here we can see that for some reason, the host is matching to the port part, which is obviously wrong. I guessed that the extra colons `:` at the beginning of the line confused the date matching and host match.

Then, I tried with adding a clear separation between the date and the host:

```
^.* haproxy\[\d+\]: <HOST>(?::\d+)?\s+.*\d* 429

# captured group: 158.118.198.219 - GOOD
```

... and it matched the address properly. You can try this in [debugexx in the expanded form](https://www.debuggex.com/r/IdU5CSdEDFCP3D-8).

At the end, I came back and found out that you were missing a space between the first colon `:` and `<HOST>`! In your example, the address context is `haproxy[1234]: <host>` and not `haproxy[1234]:<host>`

```
.*: <HOST>(?::\d+)?\s+.*\d* 429

# captured group: 158.118.198.219 - GOOD
```

[try this simpler solution in debugexx](https://www.debuggex.com/r/yzuxYPn6VOohHVHD)

Please, try it in your system and tell us if it works!